# Using Sockets with Tomcat and JSP

Tags: jsp, sockets, tomcat

I have a problem with Socket programming using Tomcat Server. I have 2 classes 1 Server and 1 Client. It works fine ( it is just an echo server ) but if i want to use my Server Class on my Tomcat to show it on a website with JSP it doesn't work. I start my Server Class and it waits for input but if i start my Client Class it says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind.

Again without Tomcat it works just fine. My port number is high enough as well. What to do?

Comment: Did you run the script twice ?

Comment: No I restarted server and eclipse etc.. Thats not the problem. Also i changed the Port a few Times so it would not matter right?

Comment: You should say how you use the `Server` class *in Tomcat*. If the server is managerd from a ServletContext level element (ie: a `ServletContextListener` starts in in init and closes it on destroy), it should work. If it is managed in `init` and `destroy` methods of a `Servlet`, it should work too. But if you start the server in the `service` method of a `Servlet` or in a JSP, you are likely to get that exception.

Comment: The *client* is binding to a port? Sounds like you're doing it wrong...